# Cancelling COBRA coverage when offered health insurance with new employer

Tags: united-states, cobra

I have elected COBRA coverage from my previous employer because my husband is continuing treatment from a surgery he had just before my departure from the employer.  Once I meet the eligibility date to elect coverage with my new employer, can I cancel the COBRA coverage - or must I carry it until the end of the coverage period?

Comment: Will your new employer's coverage cover the treatment from your husband's pre-existing surgery?

Answer (score 2):

You can cancel Cobra at any time (at least month to month). As far, as I can tell there isn't really a process for officially cancelling: you just stop paying and they interpret this as "cancellation".